# Why cant set div content to center?

Tags: html, css

I have a web chart component,and i want show center of browser,this html code:

```
<div class='center1'>

            <dxchartsui:WebChartControl ID="WebChartControl1" runat="server" CrosshairEnabled="True" Height="500px" Width="500px" AppearanceNameSerializable="Dark">
            </dxchartsui:WebChartControl>

        </div>
```

and up css code is this:

```
.center1 {

            width:800px;
            border-radius: 5px;

            width: 60%; 
            height:200px; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            align-content:center;
        }​
```

But show me this when run web page:
[image]

How can i solve that?

my complete web page html:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AR.Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_1" %>

<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v15.1.Web, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts.Web" tagprefix="dxchartsui" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v15.1.Web, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts.Web.Designer" tagprefix="dxchartdesigner" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.XtraCharts" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.1.Web, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.Web" tagprefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
        .center {

            width:800px;
            border-radius: 5px;

            width: 60%; 
            height:200px; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }​
         .center1 {

            width:800px;
            border-radius: 5px;

            width: 60%; 
            height:200px; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;

        }​
    </style>


    <style type="text/css">
    .back-link a {
        color: #4ca340;
        text-decoration: none; 
        border-bottom: 1px #4ca340 solid;
    }
    .back-link a:hover,
    .back-link a:focus {
        color: #408536; 
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px #408536 solid;
    }
    h1 {
        height: 100%;
        /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 32px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    .entry-header {
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 978px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10001;
    }
    #democontent {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
        .center1 {
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#5bb4cc">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


    <div class='center'>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
        <br />


                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Height="46px" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="شروع کن" Width="194px" />


        <br />



    </div>
        <br />
        <br />

    <div class='center1'>

        <dxchartsui:WebChartControl ID="WebChartControl1" runat="server" CrosshairEnabled="True" Height="500px" Width="685px" AppearanceNameSerializable="Dark" PaletteName="Default" style="text-align: center">
        </dxchartsui:WebChartControl>

     </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does it have `float` inherited from any other style rule ?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your HTML mark up for the page?

Comment: @afelixj please wait.

Comment: @ryandonohue please wait

Comment: why are you using `width` two times

Comment: try adding `display : block;`

Comment: i update my question,and write all html code.

Comment: pelase review that.thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using a center tag like this:

```
<center>
    <div class="center1">
        <dxchartsui:WebChartControl ID="WebChartControl1" runat="server" CrosshairEnabled="True" Height="500px" Width="500px" AppearanceNameSerializable="Dark">
        </dxchartsui:WebChartControl>
    </div>
</center>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated you should use css for this

Comment: I'm aware its deprecated, but it still works my friend

Comment: For how long? " Deprecated
This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time."

Comment: Did you just copy and paste that?

Comment: there are `"` around it so it might be a citation yes... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center Btw It is actually now [**obsolete**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements) in HTML-5

Answer (score 0):

Try add `text-align: center` to the parent of `.center1`, the `#form1` in your code. So, add this rule in css:

```
body {text-align:center;}
#form1{text-align:center;}
```

- And remove the empty rule:

`.center1 {
}`